# SPARQL BIND function Syntax error

Tags: sparql, virtuoso

Hi Guys am trying run a SPARQL query on Virtuoso version 6.1.x. Here is the query:

```sql
SPARQL PREFIX fns: <NAMESPACE> SELECT ?birth ?death ?age ?value ?typeId FROM <http://freebaseInc5> 
    WHERE {  fns:m.030pk7c fns:people.person.date_of_birth ?birth; fns:people.deceased_person.date_of_death ?death; BIND(year(?death)-year(?birth) as ?age ) .
    OPTIONAL {?mid fns:common.topic.notable_types ?type . ?type fns:type.object.id ?typeId } . 
    OPTIONAL {?mid fns:type.object.name ?value FILTER langMatches(lang(?value), "en") }}
```

I am getting the error complaining about the syntax:

```
> SQLState: 37000
Message: SQ074: Line 4: SP030: SPARQL compiler, line 2: syntax error at 'BIND' before '('
 SPARQL PREFIX fns: <NAMESPACE> SELECT ?birth ?death ?age ?value ?typeId FROM <NAMESPACE> 
    WHERE {  fns:m.030pk7c fns:people.person.date_of_birth ?birth; fns:people.deceased_person.date_of_death ?death; BIND(year(?death)-year(?birth) as ?age ) .
    OPTIONAL {?mid fns:common.topic.notable_types ?type . ?type fns:type.object.id ?typeId } . 
    OPTIONAL {?mid fns:type.object.name ?value FILTER langMatches(lang(?value), "en") }}
```

I don't see what the error is;  what am I missing?

Comment: '.' After ?death, not ';'

Comment: SPARQL PREFIX fns: <NAMESPACE> SELECT ?birth ?death ?age ?value ?typeId FROM <http://freebaseInc5> 
    WHERE {  fns:m.030pk7c fns:people.person.date_of_birth ?birth; fns:people.deceased_person.date_of_death ?death . BIND(year(?death)-year(?birth) as ?age ) .
    OPTIONAL {?mid fns:common.topic.notable_types ?type . ?type fns:type.object.id ?typeId } . 
    OPTIONAL {?mid fns:type.object.name ?value FILTER langMatches(lang(?value), "en") }}

Comment: In your second query, you seem to have added a gratuitous semi-colon behind your FROM clause.

Comment: As well as an initial "SPARQL".

Answer (score 2):

### It's actually legal SPARQL…

Here's your query, with improved formatting, and with the "SPARQL" removed from the beginning, but no other changes:

```sql
PREFIX fns: <NAMESPACE>
SELECT ?birth ?death ?age ?value ?typeId
FROM <http://freebaseInc5> 
WHERE {
  fns:m.030pk7c fns:people.person.date_of_birth ?birth ;
                fns:people.deceased_person.date_of_death ?death ;

  BIND(year(?death)-year(?birth) as ?age ) .
  OPTIONAL {
    ?mid fns:common.topic.notable_types ?type .
    ?type fns:type.object.id ?typeId
  } . 
  OPTIONAL {
    ?mid fns:type.object.name ?value
    FILTER langMatches(lang(?value), "en")
  }
}
```

According to [sparql.org's query validator](http://sparql.org/query-validator.html), the query is well formed (which actually suprised me, given the `;` after `?death`, but I guess it's OK after all).

### …but Virtuoso doesn't like it.

But if I try to run this on DBpedia's endpoint, which runs Virtuoso, (along with a limit 1, just to make sure it's not actually going to use much in the way of resources), I see the error you're talking about:

```
Virtuoso 37000 Error SP030: SPARQL compiler, line 10: syntax error at 'BIND' before '('

SPARQL query:
define sql:big-data-const 0 
#output-format:text/html
define sql:signal-void-variables 1 define input:default-graph-uri <http://dbpedia.org> PREFIX fns: <NAMESPACE>
SELECT ?birth ?death ?age ?value ?typeId
FROM <http://freebaseInc5> 
WHERE {
  fns:m.030pk7c fns:people.person.date_of_birth ?birth ;
                fns:people.deceased_person.date_of_death ?death ;

  BIND(year(?death)-year(?birth) as ?age ) .
  OPTIONAL {
    ?mid fns:common.topic.notable_types ?type .
    ?type fns:type.object.id ?typeId
  } . 
  OPTIONAL {
    ?mid fns:type.object.name ?value
    FILTER langMatches(lang(?value), "en")
  }
}
LIMIT 1
```

However, if you change the `;` after `?death` to `.`, or remove it completely, the query is accepted without any problem.

Comment: IF I don't use the BIND to function its work fine, but I need to calculate the age in the query. But with '.' after ?death didn't work to me. Guess may be the problem with the Virtuoso version am using?

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is, but can you also try `select ... (year(?death)-year(?birth) as ?age) ...  where { ... }` without the bind in it.  Virtuoso's implementation is idiosyncratic in places.

Comment: Didn't work either, now its showing syntax error: SPARQL compiler, line 1: syntax error at 'year' before '('

Comment: There's a difference between "didn't work either", which implies that you've got the same error, and a different error.  The year function was introduced in SPARQL 1.1.  Maybe the version of Virtuoso you're using only supports the original SPARQL.

Comment: Right I am upgrading the Virtuoso to 7.x Version, I need that anyways for multiple other reason :)

Comment: Updated to the 7.x Version, Query working fine now. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @geek You should probably post that as an answer and accept it, then.